# JavaFX: ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to class in TableView

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview, observablelist

I'm trying to get the values of the selected row of my table to set them into the textfields of my GUI ([click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqCRV.png)). I've read in a similar question ([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097537/javafx-tableview-get-selected-row-cell-values)) that the following method would help to solve this problem:

```
@FXML
void editCabin() {
    if(tblCabins.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
        Cabins selectedCabin = tblCabins.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        txtCabinNo.setText(String.valueOf(selectedCabin.getIntCabinNo()));
        txtDeck.setText(selectedCabin.getStrDeck());
        txtMaxPassengerCapacity.setText(String.valueOf(selectedCabin.getIntMaxPassengerCapacity()));
        txtSizeInSqm.setText(String.valueOf(selectedCabin.getDblSizeInSqM()));
        txtNoOfBeds.setText(String.valueOf(selectedCabin.getIntNoOfBeds()));
        txtNoOfToilets.setText(String.valueOf(selectedCabin.getIntNoOfToilets()));
        txtPricePerPerson.setText(String.valueOf(selectedCabin.getDblPricePerPersonInEUR()));
    }
}
```

The TableView and the TextFields are defined above as shown here:

```
@FXML private TextField txtCabinNo, txtDeck, txtMaxPassengerCapacity, txtSizeInSqm, txtNoOfBeds, txtNoOfToilets, txtPricePerPerson; 
@FXML private ComboBox<Object> cbCabinType;   
@FXML private TableView<Cabins> tblCabins;
```

But everytime I run this method I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to class org.green_pioneer.cruiseship_management.objectclasses.Cabins (com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper is in module javafx.base of loader 'app'; org.green_pioneer.cruiseship_management.objectclasses.Cabins is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

It is important to say that I'm using the dynamic table view developed by Narayan G. Maharjan and a little bit modified by me. It is located in a seperate class to save the overview of the code.

```
public TableView createAndFillTableView(ResultSet aResultSet, TableView anUnbuiltTableView) {
    ObservableList<ObservableList> observableDatalist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        /**********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
         **********************************/
        for(int i=0 ; i<aResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;                
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(aResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                    
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                              
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                        
                }                    
            });
            col.setSortable(false);
            anUnbuiltTableView.getColumns().addAll(col); 

        }
        while(aResultSet.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=aResultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(aResultSet.getString(i));
            }

            observableDatalist.add(row);
        }
        anUnbuiltTableView.setItems(observableDatalist);
        TableView aBuiltTableView = anUnbuiltTableView;
        return aBuiltTableView;
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to build the Table" + ex);
    }
    return anUnbuiltTableView;
}
```

**The Cabin class to create objects:**

```
public class Cabins {

private int     intCabinNo;
private String  strType;
private String  strDeck;
private int     intMaxPassengerCapacity;
private double  dblSizeInSqM;
private int     intNoOfBeds;
private int     intNoOfToilets;
private double  dblPricePerPersonInEUR;

public Cabins() {

}

public Cabins(String strType, String strDeck, int intMaxPassengerCapacity, double dblSizeInSqM, int intNoOfBeds,
        int intNoOfToilets, double dblPricePerPersonInEUR) {
    this.strType = strType;
    this.strDeck = strDeck;
    this.intMaxPassengerCapacity = intMaxPassengerCapacity;
    this.dblSizeInSqM = dblSizeInSqM;
    this.intNoOfBeds = intNoOfBeds;
    this.intNoOfToilets = intNoOfToilets;
    this.dblPricePerPersonInEUR = dblPricePerPersonInEUR;
}

public Cabins(int intCabinNo, String strType, String strDeck, int intMaxPassengerCapacity, double dblSizeInSqM,
        int intNoOfBeds, int intNoOfToilets, double dblPricePerPersonInEUR) {
    this.intCabinNo = intCabinNo;
    this.strType = strType;
    this.strDeck = strDeck;
    this.intMaxPassengerCapacity = intMaxPassengerCapacity;
    this.dblSizeInSqM = dblSizeInSqM;
    this.intNoOfBeds = intNoOfBeds;
    this.intNoOfToilets = intNoOfToilets;
    this.dblPricePerPersonInEUR = dblPricePerPersonInEUR;
}



public int getIntCabinNo() {
    return intCabinNo;
}

public void setIntCabinNo(int intCabinNo) {
    this.intCabinNo = intCabinNo;
}

public String getStrType() {
    return strType;
}

public void setStrType(String strType) {
    this.strType = strType;
}

public String getStrDeck() {
    return strDeck;
}

public void setStrDeck(String strDeck) {
    this.strDeck = strDeck;
}

public int getIntMaxPassengerCapacity() {
    return intMaxPassengerCapacity;
}

public void setIntMaxPassengerCapacity(int intMaxPassengerCapacity) {
    this.intMaxPassengerCapacity = intMaxPassengerCapacity;
}

public double getDblSizeInSqM() {
    return dblSizeInSqM;
}

public void setDblSizeInSqM(double dblSizeInSqM) {
    this.dblSizeInSqM = dblSizeInSqM;
}

public int getIntNoOfBeds() {
    return intNoOfBeds;
}

public void setIntNoOfBeds(int intNoOfBeds) {
    this.intNoOfBeds = intNoOfBeds;
}

public int getIntNoOfToilets() {
    return intNoOfToilets;
}

public void setIntNoOfToilets(int intNoOfToilets) {
    this.intNoOfToilets = intNoOfToilets;
}

public double getDblPricePerPersonInEUR() {
    return dblPricePerPersonInEUR;
}

public void setDblPricePerPersonInEUR(double dblPricePerPersonInEUR) {
    this.dblPricePerPersonInEUR = dblPricePerPersonInEUR;
}
```

**The code of the MySQL-DBAccessor:**

```
    public TableView showCabins(TableView aTableView, int intFirstDataSet, final int INT_DATA_LIMIT) {
    try {
        openDB();
        String strSQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM tblcabins ORDER BY tblcabins.cabinNo ASC LIMIT ?,? ;";
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(strSQLStatement);
        stmt.setInt(1, intFirstDataSet);
        stmt.setInt(2, INT_DATA_LIMIT);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        aTableViewFormatter.createAndFillTableView(rs, aTableView);
        closeDB();
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read data from tblCabins " + ex);
    }
    return aTableView;

}
```

**And the FXML-File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="1200.0" styleClass="anchorPane" stylesheets="@format.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.green_pioneer.cruiseship_management.guicontrollers.GUICabinsController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar fx:id="mbCruiseManagement" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="1200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu fx:id="mManage" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Manage">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miCabins" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cabins" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miCabinTypes" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cabintypes" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miCountries" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Countries" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miCrewpersons" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Crewpersons" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miCrewpositions" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Crew positions" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miCruises" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cruises" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miPassengers" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Passengers" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miPorts" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ports" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu fx:id="mSettings" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Settings">
               <items>
                  <Menu fx:id="mLanguage" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Language">
                     <items>
                        <RadioMenuItem fx:id="rmiEN" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="EN">
                           <toggleGroup>
                              <ToggleGroup fx:id="tgLanguage" />
                           </toggleGroup>
                        </RadioMenuItem>
                        <RadioMenuItem fx:id="rmiDE" mnemonicParsing="false" text="DE" toggleGroup="$tgLanguage" />
                     </items>
                  </Menu>
               </items>
          </Menu>
            <Menu fx:id="mShowData" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Show data">
              <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miSortByPrice" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sort by price" />
                <MenuItem fx:id="miSortBySizeInSqm" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sort by size in sq m" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblHeadline" text="Manage cabins" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="50.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" spacing="20.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="tblCabins" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="1127.0">
               <columnResizePolicy>
                  <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
               </columnResizePolicy></TableView>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="25.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="btnPreviousData" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="30.0" styleClass="buttonPrevious" text="⮜" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnShowAllData" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="buttonViewAllData" text="Show all data" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnNextData" disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="30.0" styleClass="buttonNext" text="⮞" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <VBox spacing="20.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER">
                     <children>
                        <VBox spacing="20.0">
                           <children>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblCabinNo" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefWidth="295.0" text="Cabin No:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <TextField fx:id="txtCabinNo" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="17.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </TextField>
                                 </children>
                                 <cursor>
                                    <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
                                 </cursor>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblType" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefWidth="295.0" text="Type:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <ComboBox fx:id="cbCabinType" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblDeck" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefWidth="295.0" text="Deck:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <TextField fx:id="txtDeck" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="17.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </TextField>
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblMaxPassengerCapacity" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="295.0" text="Max. passenger capacity:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <TextField fx:id="txtMaxPassengerCapacity" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="17.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </TextField>
                                 </children>
                                 <cursor>
                                    <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
                                 </cursor>
                              </HBox>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                        <VBox spacing="20.0">
                           <children>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblSizeInSqm" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefWidth="295.0" text="Size in m²:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <TextField fx:id="txtSizeInSqm" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="17.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </TextField>
                                 </children>
                                 <cursor>
                                    <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
                                 </cursor>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblNoOfBeds" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefWidth="295.0" text="No of beds:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <TextField fx:id="txtNoOfBeds" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="17.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </TextField>
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblNoOfToilets" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefWidth="295.0" text="No of toilets:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <TextField fx:id="txtNoOfToilets" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="17.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </TextField>
                                 </children>
                              </HBox>
                              <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="50.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Label fx:id="lblPricePerPerson" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="295.0" text="Price per person in EUR:" textFill="WHITE">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="26.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <TextField fx:id="txtPricePerPerson" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font size="17.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </TextField>
                                 </children>
                                 <cursor>
                                    <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
                                 </cursor>
                              </HBox>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnSave" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="buttonSave" text="Save" />
            <Button fx:id="btnEdit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editCabin" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="buttonEdit" text="Edit" />
            <Button fx:id="btnDelete" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="buttonDelete" text="Delete" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the _M_!

Comment: Why are you using this very general structure, when you know your table view is populated by rows represented by your `Cabins` class (which should really be called `Cabin`)? The class cast exception occurs because you put an `ObservableList<String>` in each row in the table, but when you get the selected item you (silently) cast it to a `Cabins`. Bottom line here: *never* use raw types.

Comment: Do you mean the general structure in the TableBuilder ? This method builds tables from the database dynamically. Therefore, I can use this to build different tables from another classes.

@kleopatra I've added some more code that you can reproduce the error easier.

Comment: @Chipmaster5 Yes, exactly. This (very low quality) code you have borrowed from elsewhere (in your `createAndFillTableView` method) is designed for when you don't know the structure of the content of the database ahead of time. In your case, you do know that structure: you've even written a class for it already. So just create instances of that class from the result set and use them to populate the table. If you really want to use a general method like this, you should improve it, throw out your `Cabins` (sic) class, and update your `editCabin()` method. But the first approach is much better.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your help. I redesigned the code and put the data into an `observablelist` in the method, which returns it. After that, I can easily fill the table with the items. I used the SceneBuilder to create the columns and it was easier than I thought.