# Troubleshooting Populating a tableview with Sqlite JavaFx

Tags: sqlite, javafx, tableview, observablelist

I am trying to populate a tableview with Javafx, the database test.db contains warehouses table with three fields, "id", "name", and "capacity".
The following code is a sample program

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class javafxsqliteconntable extends Application {


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

       primaryStage.setTitle("Que onda");
       Label etiqueta = new Label("Hola Mundo");
       Button boton = new Button("Presionar aqui");
       
         TableView tableView = new TableView();
         
         TableColumn<Integer, Person> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
         
        TableColumn<String, Person> column2 = new TableColumn<>("name");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));

        TableColumn<Double, Person> column3 = new TableColumn<>("capacity");
        column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Capacity"));
        
        tableView.getColumns().add(column1);
        tableView.getColumns().add(column2);
        tableView.getColumns().add(column3);
        
         VBox vbox = new VBox(20, etiqueta, boton, tableView);
         ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String sql = "SELECT id, name, capacity FROM warehouses";
        
        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){
          
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") +  "\t" + rs.getString("name") + "\t" + rs.getDouble("capacity"));   
               data.addAll(new Person(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getDouble("capacity")));
            }
             
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 300, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

primaryStage.show();
}
public class Person {
    private int Id;
    private String Nombre = null;
    private Double Capacidad = null;

   public Person(int id, String nombre, Double capacidad) {
       this.Id=id;
       this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Capacidad = capacidad;
    }

     public int getId(){
     return Id;
     
     }
     
    public String getnombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

 
    public Double getcapacidad() {
        return Capacidad;
    }

}

 private Connection connect() {
         String url ="jdbc:sqlite:test.db";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

when i compiled i do not have any kind of errors, the sqlite connection is succesfully established, and the line

```
 System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") +  "\t" + rs.getString("name") + "\t" + rs.getDouble("capacity"));
```

gives the information correctly in the console command line but

```
data.addAll(new Person(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getDouble("capacity")));
```

does not give me anything in the Tableview, am I missing something?, i made the observablelist and i already have the class person inside the program.
anyhelp is appreciated in order to get the data populated in tableview javafx
Thank you in advance,any help is appreciated

Comment: type parameters of columns are the wrong way round

Comment: Additionally, it should be a `TableView<Person>`. Never use raw types

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExample

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097537/javafx-tableview-get-selected-row-cell-values

Comment: still the same troubleshooting, populate a Dataview with JavaFX is very hard, it was more simple with java swing